# MySQL escape everything (all special characters)

Tags: mysql, sql, django, search

I am making a mysql query to select something where a value is `LIKE query_search`

What I want to achieve is to search the exact `query_search` passed as a parameter to the query.
For example if `query_search` is one of the following: `%admin`, `you're\` , `'/_%'` , I only want to look for entries with exact matching.

For `%admin` I only want to find the entry `%admin` , but `myadmin` should not be found.

So, how to escape all the mysql special characters?

Putting `\` in front of each character of `query_search` would be a good solution?

For **Django** knowers, I am using the

```
something.extra(
   where=['value like convert(_utf8%s using utf8)'],
   params=query_search,
)
```

where `something` is a QuerySet. I am using MySQL as a DB and I receive `query_search` as a parameter. Maybe there is another way to achieve this with Django.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can [use `contains`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#contains) (or `icontains`) in a `Queryset.filter`:

```
something.filter(value__contains=query_search)
```

Comment: I have an API method for my project which allows multiple types of search. `def search(keyword, type)`. for example if type is 2, it allows searching for suffixes. So if `keyword='adm'` it should find 'administration'. if `keyword='adm%'` it should find nothing. THis is why I must trick the mysql. I think your answer is ok for me. I can first do the `contains` filter and then, depending on `type` I can make further filtering. good point